# Use control panel for discord bot with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-asyncio, discord.py

I want to do a control panel for my discord bot in python with PyQt5. I have already my window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1023, 457)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
       
#some other widgets

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 30, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

#some other widgets
```

and the main code :

```
import discord
import sys
from window import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

prefix = ""
bot = discord.Client

class MyClient(bot):

    async def on_connect(self):
        print("Bot connected to")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

        for guild in self.guilds:
            if guild.id == 354061299596132392:
                print("guild find")


    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)

    async def on_diconnect(self):
        print("bot disconnected")



def launcher():
    client = MyClient()
    client.run('TOKEN')



def windowLauncher():



    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(launcher)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


windowLauncher()
```

but when I execute this main code, the window is started and when I push the button to start the bot, the window crash, but the bot is running. I have already try to use threading but without success.

Comment: Can't you just use threading to run both event loops at the same time? Because your problem looks like it comes from the dual event loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

discord uses async which has its own event loop and Qt handles another event loop causing one to block the other. In this case, the solution is that both use the same event loop and there are several libraries that implement it:

- [`qasync`](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync) (`python -m pip install qasync`)
- [`asyncqt`](https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt) (`python -m pip install asyncqt`)

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import asyncio
import sys

import discord
from qasync import QEventLoop, asyncSlot
# or
# from asyncqt import QEventLoop, asyncSlot

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from window import Ui_MainWindow


prefix = ""


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_connect(self):
        print("Bot connected to")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

        for guild in self.guilds:
            if guild.id == 354061299596132392:
                print("guild find")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)

    async def on_diconnect(self):
        print("bot disconnected")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.client = MyClient()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    @asyncSlot()
    async def on_clicked(self):
        await self.client.start("YOUR_TOKEN")


def windowLauncher():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    windowLauncher()
```

Comment: @FabienDenoyelle avoid providing sensitive information such as the token, password, etc.

Comment: Is there a comparison between `asyncqt` or `qasync`? If my understanding is correct, `qasync` started out as a fork of `asyncqt` intended as a continuation, since `asyncqt` appeared unmaintained at the time. But maintenance of `asyncqt` later resumed, so the two ended up as competitors. As with every open-source fork, having both leads to duplication of effort and splintering of the ecosystem splintered, in this case without a sound engineering reason, such as important innovations or differences in choice of tradeoffs. They exist in parallel by pure historical accident.

Comment: @user4815162342 What you indicate at the beginning is correct, qasync is a fork of asynqt since it had several initial bugs and the repo was not active, after a while both repos are updated (they eliminated historical bugs). That is pointed out in the qasync README

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Still, are there known differences between them now? Something that would be relevant when choosing which one to use in a project.

Comment: @user4815162342 mmm, no relevant difference

Comment: @user4815162342 The story is simple: 1) asyncqt was not active, 2) A relevant bug arose (I had problems executing discord, so I had to do tricks to make a simple application work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59274707), 3) Someone did a fork and I fixed it: qasync, 4) asyncqt got active again and also fixed that bug.