# PyQt5 with Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, discord.py

So I want to create Discord app using PyQt5 and because of both blocks each other.
No it's not a duplicate of [Question 61664473](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664473/use-control-panel-for-discord-bot-with-pyqt5), because I tried this and no matter how I tried nothing works.
In addition, I was searching for solution since two days with no results.

I didn't add any code. I want to know how should I do it properly.

Comment: why using discord.py at all? simply make HTTP requests to the discord API, I made an example a while ago on [how to send a message using the API](https://gist.github.com/Kwieeciol/50cca99f495178cf6c49593e03dfff54)

Comment: Well, I don't want to only send messages. I want to create something like "_Discord Bot Client_",

Comment: what is your definition of a *"Discord Bot Client"*?

Comment: By saying "_DIscord Bot Client_" I meant a regular Discord client, but made for controlling bot. Something reversed to Discord's ToS. It says that you can't automate user account, but it's not mentioned that you can't manually control bots.

Comment: Probably your only hope is to use threading